# How do I make this scroll layout work?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am currently trying to get my UI to have a Title Bar, a bottom Button bar, with a ScrollView in between. I can get bits and pieces of it to work, but once I get a different piece working, the old part goes back to not showing up. Here is a picture of my UI on the left, with what I want it to look like on the right...(sorry for the sloppiness, I edited it in MS Paint :P )

To sum it up, I want the Version and Type fields to be moved with room for the other TextViews in the XML file, and I want both buttons to appear on the bottom bar.

[image]

EDIT :

The buttons on the bottom should be equal in size, I'm not too talented in making boxes in MS Paint

EDIT 2 :
Sorry....here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SN : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serialNumberView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ver : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versionView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Type : " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/floatCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Float" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/tripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Trip" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/closeCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/blockedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Blocked" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/hardTripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hard Trip" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/phaseAngleCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase angle wrong for closing" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/diffVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Differential volts too low" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/networkVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Network volts too low to close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Using Defaults( Reprogram )" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/relaxedCloseActiveCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Relaxed Close Active" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/commBoardDetectedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Comm Board Detected" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/antiPumpBlock"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Anti-Pump Block" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/motorCutoffCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Motor Cutoff Inhibit" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/phaseRotationCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase Rotation Wrong" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultDNPCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text= "Using Default DNP Profile" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Read" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1.0" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:weightSum="9"
       android:gravity="center"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="SN : "

                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serialNumberView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                 android:layout_weight="2" 
                 android:text="saasdasd ssadasd sadas asd sd sd"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ver : "
                 android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versionView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:layout_weight="2"
                  android:text="saasdasd ssadasd sadas asd sd sd" 
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Type : "
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                   android:layout_weight="1" 

                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:layout_weight="2" 
                   android:text="saasdasd ssadasd sadas asd sd sd" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">


                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/floatCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Float" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/tripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Trip" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/closeCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/blockedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Blocked" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/hardTripCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Hard Trip" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/phaseAngleCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase angle wrong for closing" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/diffVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Differential volts too low" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/networkVoltsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Network volts too low to close" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultsCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Using Defaults( Reprogram )" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/relaxedCloseActiveCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Relaxed Close Active" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/commBoardDetectedCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Comm Board Detected" />

                    <CheckBox 
                        android:id="@+id/antiPumpBlock"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Anti-Pump Block" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/motorCutoffCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Motor Cutoff Inhibit" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/phaseRotationCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Phase Rotation Wrong" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/usingDefaultDNPCheck"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text= "Using Default DNP Profile" />
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Back"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Read"
            android:layout_weight=".5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: is any thing more you needed ?

Comment: That worked very well for the buttons, but now the 3 TextViews WITH text are just centered, while the three WITHOUT text are still hidden. What I am trying to do is leave those textViews blank, because when the user presses the Read button on the bottom, it will read from another device and display that devices information. I would like there to already be space so things don't move around so much when the text is loaded

Comment: can use android:layout_weight and put the the _weight to each as per their need........

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, the Buttons are perfect now. What would I put their weight set to? The only time i've ever seen weight used it is set to "1.0"

Answer (score 2):

change the buttons to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
you also can enter a value in `sp` or `dip` for `wrap_content`

and add at the text `android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the buttons use

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

I am not sure how to help you with the other issues, try to give them some left-margin.

Answer (score 1):

`Use` **Table Layout** `along with` **Table Row** `to place both the buttons at the bottom` `side to side.`

Answer (score 1):

This should help. The title's are separated by spaces, but you could do something a little different to make it look nicer.

Updated with padding and `TableLayout` for `TextViews`.

XML:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="SN: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="Test" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="Ver: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="Test" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="Type: " />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4"
            android:text="Test" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/floatCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Float" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/tripCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trip" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/closeCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/blockedCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Blocked" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/hardTripCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hard Trip" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/phaseAngleCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phase angle wrong for closing" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/diffVoltsCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Differential volts too low" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/networkVoltsCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Network volts too low to close" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/usingDefaultsCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Using Defaults( Reprogram )" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/relaxedCloseActiveCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Relaxed Close Active" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/commBoardDetectedCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Comm Board Detected" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/antiPumpBlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Anti-Pump Block" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/motorCutoffCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motor Cutoff Inhibit" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/phaseRotationCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phase Rotation Wrong" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/usingDefaultDNPCheck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Using Default DNP Profile" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Back" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Read" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Example Picture:
[image]

Comment: I would like to have the 6 TextViews spaced equally along the width of the View

Comment: Added some better spacing with `TableLayout`. Edit the `padding` to get a better idea of what type of `padding` you want or how much. You can change the padding type. There is `paddingLeft`, paddingRight`, `paddingTop` and `paddingBottom`.

Comment: This implementation will not handle the worst case for the `TextViews` though. Like the answer from Dheeresh Singh.

Comment: I am using what Dheeresh posted, thank you for your input though.